# Validation error occurs when binding DateTime? with MudBlazor's MudTextField

Tags: c#, blazor, nullable, mudblazor, mudtextfield

I set MudTextField's `InputType` to `DateTimeLocal` and bound it to the `DateTime?` member, but a validation error occurs in Visual Studio 2019, using .NET 5.0 and MudBlazor 5.2.5.

```
<MudTextField Format="s" InputType="InputType.DateTimeLocal" @bind-Value="testdate" />

@code {
    private DateTime? testdate { get; set; }
}
```

Form error screenshot:

[image: form error]

As mentioned above, I tried to isolate the problem by simplifying the code as much as possible, but I can't dig any further.

I searched as much as I could, but I couldn't find a topic with the same problem.

I would like advice from someone who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use: `T="DateTime?"`**

```
<MudTextField T="DateTime?" Format="s" InputType="InputType.DateTimeLocal" @bind-Value="testdate" />

@code {
    private DateTime? testdate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In addition, Format="s" didn't work, I had to use Format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm".